# 12.04 installing lexmark s605 on network

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, lexmark

I haven't used unix for twenty years, heaven help us I was a unix box product manager once.  My how it's changed, I'll call myself a newbie.  Anyway:

I have a lexmark S605 printer on the network.  it works fine from the windows machines. (not really fine but that's beside the point).

I know its ip address 192.168.1.38.  It's definitely there if I enter the ip address in the browser I get a status screen with ink levels etc.
I have downloaded  `lexmark-printer-utility-1.0-2.amd64.deb` and software centre tells me it's been installed.

Tried in `System Settings` > `printing` > `Add` > `Network Printing` - `host 192.168.1.38`, and press `find`
It gives me port 9100, and declares this is a jetdirect (?). Then pressed `Forward`, it searches endlessly for drivers.  Cancel/

I am offered:

select drivers from database but that isn't showing my printer ,

provide PPD isn't right (is it?)

search for a driver again gets nowhere

I'm somewaht narked lexmark don't appear to give any sort of guide, and I'm feeling rather dumb.

Can some one point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Ubuntu and hope I can help you since I had the same problem with Lexmark Platinum Pro 905.

I have Ubuntu 12.4.  and this is how I got my printer to work.

I found this page http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=lexmark_linux&num=4, and installed the packages the writer suggested. The Lexmark file is (.deb) and it has to be installed using Debian Package Manager.  Since i could not find Debian Package Manager, I installed instead the QApt Package Installer from Ubuntu Software Center (Go to Ubuntu Software Center and in the search box enter "deb"), then i downloaded the printer file.
This is what i did next:
I selected the file, right clicked on it and selected the option to open with QApt Package Installer.  After the driver was installed i proceeded to add a new printer.  I selected network printer then from the options i selected the one that had "lxhcp".  After that i selected the driver for the printer and printed test page, and other documents without any problems.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you include the commands that worked in your answer.